# How do I add text labels of bin contents when drawing bar charts using pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, bar-chart

I want to create a bar chart using the pandas plot() function, where each bar has a text label, showing exact number it is visually representing.

In addition, I would like to be able to be able to format the labels, for example rounding to the nearest integer.

Comment: There is an example for the first part of this task on the matplotlib website:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

However, I don't understand how to access the rects2 variable they pass to autolabel when using the DataFrame.plot() function.

Comment: This gives you the axis object after calling plot(), ax = plt.gca()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case you haven't figured it out yet, here is some working code that combines the Matplotlib API with pandas plotting in the way you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dummy data
x = range(1, 5)
y = [i**(0.5) for i in x]
ser = pd.Series(y, index=x)

ax1 = ser.plot(kind='bar')  # plot with pandas and assign to an axis object

# Grab the patches from the axis and plot the text near them, rounding to 1dp
for rect in ax1.patches:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax1.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, round(height, 1),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Answer (score 2):

The above code doesn't place the text properly if values are negative.

You can directly read the height from the Series and finetune the distances depending on positive or negative values (replacing the last section of rauparaha's answer):

```
for rect, var in zip(ax1.patches, ser.index):        
    height = ser[var]

    if height > 0:
        ypos = 1.01*height
    else:
        ypos = height - 3 # with my data I had to use an absolute value to make it look nicely

    ax1.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., ypos, round(height, 1),
            ha='center', va='bottom')
```